# When running R, how to exit from Emacs-ESS gracefully?

Tags: r, ess

Sometimes, right after I submit a computation-intensive run to R in ESS, my whole screen freezes. When that happens, none of the Emacs commands work (I use laptop running XP). My crude solution is to press Control-Alt-Del, go to the Task Manager, and kill the R process, not the Emacs process. (I actually use Process Explorer). Once I kill the R process, I get the Emacs buffers back, but lose the R session. I can then do Meta-R and start again.

Does anyone know of a more graceful way to exit/abort from R within ESS?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Control-G will get you control of emacs again. Then control-C twice will interrupt R and probably get your prompt back.

Comment: The last 2 times it happened, it didn't respond to Control-G. I didn't know about the double Control-C to interrupt R. Will try that. Thanks, Spacedman.

Comment: Sometimes hitting Control-G several times like a crazy person seems necessary to beat emacs into submission. The other way of sending a Control-C to R from ESS is via one of the menu options.

Comment: @Spacedman Could you please tell which menu option you are referring to ?